# Some question about the date in this sentence, I saw your advertisement on 16th October, 2017

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I saw your advertisement in a newspaper on 12th October, 2017

When I wrote this message and when people saw it, what would they think of the date in this message? I mean I am not sure whether the date (12th October 2017) was the date when the advertisement was published in the newspaper, or it was the date when I saw the newspaper.

If the newspaper with the advistement was published on 12th October 2017, but I saw the newspaper some days later, say I saw it on 16th October 2017, 
How should I tell people about this?

Should I write

> I saw your advertisement in a newspaper on 12th October, 2017

or

> I saw your advertisement in a newspaper on 16th October, 2017

or

> I saw your advertisement in a newspaper published on 12th October 2017 but I saw it on 16th October, 2017.

But the 3rd sentence is clumsy.

Comment: I believe the original poster of the advertisement will know the date he had it published. So he wouldn't be confused, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I saw your advertisement in a newspaper on 12th October, 2017**

**When I wrote this message and when people saw it, what would they think of the date in this message?**

--> My initial understanding is that you saw the advertisement on the 12th of October.

One good way to remove ambiguity is to write:

> On 16 October 2017, I saw your advertisement in a newspaper dated 12 October 2017.

IMO, using the word **[dated](https://www.google.co.jp/search?source=hp&q=dated+definition&oq=dated+definition&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i5i30i19k1l3j0i5i10i30i19k1l2j0i5i30i19k1.2241.4029.0.4190.16.9.0.0.0.0.489.768.2-1j0j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..14.2.766....0.tWMqXaezrm4&safe=active&ssui=on)** to indicate date marks on publications/emails, etc., is effective (and provides clarity in cases similar to this question).

There might be other answers based on varying context, but I suggest using the pattern of the sentence above to provide unambiguous information (in general).